# How to get time with react-native-date-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to get the time with `react-native-date-picker`. So I set the mode as `time`. But this gives in this format, Here time is not correct too.

```
2023-01-25T16:50:53.467Z
```

This is my code,

```
     <DatePicker
        mode="time"
        date={date}
        modal
        open={pickupTimeModal1}
        onConfirm={time => console.log(time)}
        onCancel={() => {
          setPickupTimeModal1(false);
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this library gives you an entire date string.
You can convert the date to a format that you like:

```
new Date(Date.parse("2023-01-25T16:50:53.467Z")).toLocaleString();
// 1/25/2023, 8:50:53 PM
new Date(Date.parse("2023-01-25T16:50:53.467Z")).toLocaleDateString();
// 1/25/2023
new Date(Date.parse("2023-01-25T16:50:53.467Z")).toLocaleTimeString();
//8:50:53 PM
```

for better conversion, you can also use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)

Answer (score 1):

```
  let d = new Date();
  let hours = d.getHours();
  let minutes = d.getMinutes();
  let seconds = d.getSeconds() <= 9 ? `0${d.getSeconds()}` : d.getSeconds();

  console.log(`${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.